# Install kernel headers using Kernel 6.8 and Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, 24.04

Apparently I'm trying to install kernel headers but it complains about libc6 being too old. I searched Google and from what I can tell upgrading it would "send the system into chaos" and make everything unstable. I'm trying to install the latest mainline headers for openrazer support.

Output of `uname -r`:

`6.8.1-060801-generic`

Comment: Upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 beta instead. It will have kernel 6.8, with an updated version of libc6

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi FYI: *beta freeze* isn't until 1 April 2024, with *beta* scheduled to be reached/released on 4 April 2024... We're still in March (*alpha*)  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649

Comment: I'm actually using 22.04. The title was a typo.

Comment: By "beta", I meant the current development version of 24.04

Comment: Please check here: https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.8.1/